# How do I call all DerivedClass object functions of the same name from it's BaseClass function?

Tags: c#

I need all the previous functions to be called rather than be overridden by the DerivedClass function.

```
public class Program
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        public int BaseClassData = 123;
        public virtual void ResetAllData()
        {
            BaseClassData = 0;
        }

    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public int ChildClassData = 456;
        public override void ResetAllData()
        {
            ChildClassData = 0;

        }
    }



    public static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass subject = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedClass subject2 = new DerivedClass();

        (subject).ResetAllData();
        Console.WriteLine(subject.BaseClassData+", "+subject.ChildClassData); // this needs to return 0, 0

        (subject2 as BaseClass).ResetAllData();
        Console.WriteLine(subject2.BaseClassData+", "+subject2.ChildClassData); // and this needs to return 0, 0

    }
}
```

Using virtual and override seems to be the right direction since calling the function will return the same result regardless of conversion to it's base class in subject2 (which is another thing I need) but neither will call previous versions of itself.

Is there an efficient way to do this without copying everything from the BaseClass function into the overriding function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access members of the base class using the keyword `base`. So within your child's overridden method, just call `base.ResetAllData()`.